# Display Drop down options on right side of image

Tags: magento

You can see text "MEN" & drop-down options below image

[image]

You can see text "MEN" & drop-down options on right side of image

[image]

i want to display "MEN" & drop-down options on right side of image for link1

```
.product-options dd select {
    width: 330px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
select {
    font-size: 14px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
body, button, input, select, table, textarea {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: #636363;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to : Catalog > Products.
2. Edit `Together Forever` product.
3. Select `Design` Tab
4. Change `Display product options in` select box to `Product Info Column`
5. Save